# Sqlite exception on sqlbatch execution

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic2, android-sqlite

I am integrating SQLite in my ionic application. While executing the code getting following error.

***ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: a statement with no error handler failed: sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: incomplete input
Error: a statement with no error handler failed: sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: incomplete input***

my code as below.

```
createEncryptedDB() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'sampleDb',
        location: 'default',
        key: 'mypassword'
      }).then((sqlObject: SQLiteObject) => {
        this.db = sqlObject;
        const tableList: any = [];
        tableList.push(['CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST_DATA(kty text, kty_type varchar(30)']);
        this.queryAll(tableList).then(() => { 
           console.log("Tables were created")
         }).catch((ex) => {
            return Promise.reject(ex);
          });
        });
    });
  }

  public queryAll(list: any[]): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          resolve();
          return this.db.sqlBatch(list);         
        });
      } catch (err) {
        reject({ err: err });
      }
    });
```

Please note that we are encrypting the database. Can anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in the `CREATE TABLE` command. It is missing a final closing `)`.  That may not be the only error in the code, but it explains this specific failure.